# Charts and Tabs ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am currently working on a project that is dealing with charts and tabs within an ASP.NET page. I am assigned to create a chart that will be generated from an array and a menu like system using tabs to select different options for the chart.

I have no idea how to implement this, I am using VS Web Developer 2010. I am new to ASP.NET framework and how to implement charts and tabs with this information. Basically it will be a form that the user will submit options and it will calculate a forecast of payments based on the options selected.

Please help, not sure where to even begin with ASP.NET. I have seen some things regarding AJAX controls but for some reason the controls are not loaded into VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For charts you can use [asp.net chart control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/07/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx)

I don't understand the part of the menu, but I think you can use the tabcontrol in the containers section of the toolbox

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend looking at [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). It's a JavaScript library for rendering charts. It will create charts on the client-side so I'm not sure whether it meets your requirements (there are other products that support server-side generation of charts but I'm less familiar with these).

I'm not sure what you mean by using tabs for selecting different options, but Highcharts does have a lot of different rendering models and looks really good.

Take a look at their [demo gallery](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) and [documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use) for more information.

Comment: I don't want to use client side software because i don't know what the client will have. I was looking at Ajax tabs kind of like tabs in VB.net. I have a program that have tabs for options. I kind of the Web app to look almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reluctant to use client side charting solutions, try [Highcharts.Net](http://highcharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/79560). It is a C# wrapper written around the Highcharts JS library. So you write all your code using Classes and objects in C#, and the library translates that into JS.

The added bonus is that you get to use ASP .Net's state management for data persistence. The project also has samples that can be downloaded [here](http://highcharts.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets).

If you are using MVC, you could try out [DotNet.Highcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/85324) along with samples.